# Addressing View Controller through code

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, ibaction, uistoryboardsegue

I'm inheriting a view controller with buttons across multiple view controllers in my application. I want to be able to implement segues correctly. I want an if statement saying if viewcontroller A, then perform segue A, if B, then B and so on. Example:

```
-(IBAction)firstButtonPressed:(id)sender
{ 
    if (storyboard.viewcontroller == a) // If the current view controller Is A
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueA" sender:self];
    }
    if(storyboard.viewcontroller == b)//If the current view controller is B
    {
        [self.performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueB" sender:self];
    }
}
```

I have given my view controller storyboard ID's and checked on Use storyboard ID but am not sure how to address them in code.

Comment: Can you explain "buttons across multiple view controllers"?

Comment: @Thorsten I'm inheriting the same view controller where I Create buttons from different view controllers. SO, say View controller H creates the buttons, I"m inheriting this from VC A, VC B and VC C.

Comment: Is the code you posted above in the controller you're inheriting from?

Comment: Not really sure what else is going on, or if this code is intended to be just a sample, but you are assigning storyboard.viewController to a new value not comparing it.  you should be using == not =.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, thats my intention, that's how I see it working. And. yeah the = is a foolish mistake.

Comment: The storyboard.viewcontroller is just my logic, What is the proper way to actually do that?

Comment: What do you have in the storyboard in the way of segues? Do you have a bunch of segues going from a button in this parent controller to other controllers?

Comment: I don't actually since I thought that wouldn't help me, since my segues will never start from my parent  and will actually always start from my children controllers. I have segues from all the children controllers to the controller where they're supposed to go to.

Comment: Again, all I really need is a way to address the current view controller in my code. So, I could be able to do something like this: if (current viewcontroller == viewcontroller A) { do this}
else do that;